Lemma about Minkowski Functional in topological vector spaces
I am trying to prove the following lemma:
Suppose $X$ is a topological vector space.
Show that if $S \subseteq X$ is a convex (open) neighborhood of $0$ there exists a non-negative continuous sublinear functional $p$ such that $S=\{x \in X | p(x)<1 \}$.
Approach:
I defined the minkowski functional of the set $S$,
$p_S(x):=inf\{t>0 | x \in tS\}$.
I was able to show that $p_S$ is a sublinear functional, i.e. $p_S(x+y)\leq p_S(x)+p_S(y)$ and $p_S(\lambda x)=\lambda x$ for $\lambda \geq 0$
Non-negativity follows by definition.
My Problem:
I do not know how to show that $p_S$ is continuous and $S=\{x \in X | p(x)<1 \}$.
I am trying to understand why the statement is true. So I would appreciate some Help or a Solution or a reference to a boot where this lemma is proven.

Is your neighbourhood open?

@blomp yes, I do assume the neighborhood to be open (I added it to the post)

First of all, the fact that $S = \{x \in X : p(x) <1 \}$ follows from:

if $x \in S$, then you can find $\lambda <1$ such that $\lambda x \in S$ too, since $S$ open.
Conversely, if $p_S(x) < 1$, then there is $t < 1$ such that $x \in t S$. Since $0 \in S$ and $t^{-1} x \in S$, by convexity $x \in S$.

For continuity see here for example.
